# Как работает данный код? Почему объект выводиться?

Tags: javascript

js

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',(e)=>{
   obj = {
      '1': one,
      '2': two,
      '3': three,
      '4': four,
      'ArrowLeft': left,
      'ArrowRight': right,
   }[e.key] // как работает данная часть кода? тут не понятно
   obj?.(e.key)// здесь понятно
})

function one(e){
   console.log(e)
}
function two(e){
   console.log(e)
}
function three(e){
   console.log(e)
}
function four(e){
   console.log(e)
}
function left(e){
   console.log(e)
}
function right(e){
   console.log(e)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос

```
obj = {
      '1': one,
      '2': two,
      '3': three,
      '4': four,
      'ArrowLeft': left,
      'ArrowRight': right,
   }[e.key] // как работает данная часть кода? тут не понятно
```

можно переписать так

```
  let obj = {
      '1': one,
      '2': two,
      '3': three,
      '4': four,
      'ArrowLeft': left,
      'ArrowRight': right,
   };// Создание и присвоение объекта;

   let func = obj[e.key]; // взятие значения свойства e.key объекта obj и присвоение переменной func
```

Поскольку у вас 2 операции производятся за раз. То в obj у вас может храниться указатель на функцию.